# What is the cardinality of the set of all non-measurable sets in $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The cardinality of the set of all measurable sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be shown to be the same as the power set of $\Bbb{R}$ by looking into Cantor set.

> Denote $M=$$\{$$Ω⊆\Bbb{R}^n:Ω$ is measurable$\}$, then $card(M)≤card(2^\Bbb{R})$. The Cantor set is measurable, has measure zero and has the same cardinality of $\Bbb{R} ⇒$ every subset of Cantor set is measurable $⇒ card(M)≥card(2^\Bbb{R} )⇒card(M)=card(2^\Bbb{R} )$.

I am wondering what is the cardinality of the set of all non-measurable sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$? I know a theorem guarantees every non-empty open sets in $\Bbb{R}$ has a non-measurable subsets, is this useful to show the cardinality of all non-measurable sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$? Thank you!

Comment: yes;how many open sets are there?

Comment: @Tony: While obvious from your question, maybe a good idea to mention you are working on the Real line.

Comment: @learnmore but it seems the cardinality of the set of all open sets is the same as $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: Careful: A priori it is not given that the Borel sets and its completion w.r.t. Lebesgue measure have same cardinality, and, AFAIK, they indeed have different cardinalities.

Answer (score 12):

Given that $(0,1)$ has a non-measurable subset, adding points in $(1,2)$ can't make it measurable.  There are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets of $(1,2)$, so take your non-measurable subset of $(0,1)$ union each subset of $(1,2)$.

Comment: There are $2^c$ subsets of $(1,2).$

Comment: @zhw.:  Thanks.  Fixed the oversight.

Comment: Nice, your proof is easier than mine.

Comment: Can you outline why their union cannot become Borel? Thanks.

Comment: @Freeze_S:  Because the two intervals are disjoint.  If the subset of $(0,1)$ is not Borel, adding points outside the interval cannot make it Borel.

Comment: I don't see why, yet. What I have in mind is $\mathbb{V}\cup\mathbb{V}^\complement$.

Comment: By the way just to be clear: Are we talking about Borel or Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: @Freeze_S:  It doesn't matter.  Any superset of a non-measurable subset of $(0,1)$ that doesn't add points inside $(0,1)$ will be non-measurable.  Most sets are non-measurable. Intuitively, the only way to have a superset of a non-measurable set become measurable is to fill it in so the fuzzy stuff isn't fuzzy any more.  You can't do that adding points outside the interval.

Comment: @RossMillikan I know this is a very old post, but what do you mean when you say "most sets are non-measurable"? Aren't the cardinalities of measurable and non-measurable sets the same as you showed above?

Comment: @HritRoy:  yes, the cardinalities of the measurable and nonmeasurable sets are the same.  This is very informal in the sense that most naturals are not primes.  To make it precise you would have to define a measure on the power set of $\Bbb R$, which I don't know how to do.  But generally, most descriptions we have of sets are too simple and smooth for those sets to be common and the really junky ones are most of what there is.

Comment: And guess the reason why the above is true is that intersection of two measurable sets is measurable (and so conversely, if we intersect the set with an interval, and get a non-measurable set, the original set must be non-measurable).

Answer (score 9):

Take your favorite nonmeasurable set $E \subset (1,2).$ Let $K\subset [0,1]$ be the Cantor set. Then $\{E \cup F: F\subset K\}$ is a collection of non measurable sets (because throwing in a set of measure $0$ can't turn a nonmeasurable set into a measurable one). Since the cardinality of $K$ is $c,$ we see there are $2^c$ sets $F$ that can be used in the above union, and distinct $F$'s give distinct unions. It follows that there are $2^c$ nonmeasurable subsets of $\mathbb R .$

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: I am trying to do a Schroeder Bernstein: 
Let N be the collection of non-measurable subsets.
1)There are at most $2^{\mathbb c}$ non-measurable subsets, since there are at most $2^{\mathbb c}$ subsets. This is the point I was trying to make in 1), though not in the clearest way. 
2) There are at least $2^{\mathbb c}$ non-measurable subsets, by a translation argument.

1)Well, the total number of  subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ is $|2^{|\mathbb R|}$| and the cardinality of all open sets is $|\mathbb R|$ . Now you have an expression $|A|=|B \cup C|$, where A represents all sets and $B$ represents all measurable sets and $B \cap C = ${}. and you know two infinite cardinalities. Now, choose your set theory and do your cardinal arithmetic. EDIT: this was not a clear way of making

*So $|N|\leq 2^{\mathbb c} $

2)Let's work in $\mathbb R^1$. I claim there are $2^{\mathbb R}$ non-measurable subsets.
  Let $T$ be non-measurable. Then, for every non-zero Real a, the set $T+a$:={$t+a: t \in T$} is also non-measurable; if it was measurable, then $T=T+a-a$ would be the translation of a measurable set and so measurable. Since there are $\mathbb R$ choices for $a$, this means there are at least $2^{\mathbb R}$ non-measurable subsets of the Reals.

** So $|N| \geq 2^{\mathbb c} $

---

From *, ** , and Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein, there are $2^{\mathbb c}$ non-measurable subsets.

EDIT: My apologies, this is unifinished, I don't have time at the moment to
finish it. IfIa m unable to finish it /correct it in a few days, I will just
delete it.

Comment: And infinite cardinal arithmetic does not have subtraction.

Comment: The argument in 1) seems correct. However in (2) the translates $T_a$ are not necessarily disjoin (e.g. let $A\subseteq[0,1]$ be non measurable and define $T=A+\mathbb{Z}$. Then $B$ is non-measurable and $T+k=T$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$). Maybe you can work something out by proving that the set of $a$ for which $T+a$ has cardinaly $<|\mathbb{R}|$, maybe for a specific $T$, e.g. a Vitali set, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Questioner: I think you misunderstood what I wrote: T+k, for $k \in \mathbb Z$  is not, as a subset of the Reals, the same as $T+k'$ , for $k' : k \in \mathbb Z$ I did not claim that no two were disjoint, just that they are, as sets, different. This means that for every fixed Real $a$, I get a different set $T+a$.  And we are counting the cardinality of subsets, whether they overlap or not.  If $T$ is non-measurable, then, for any $a$, $T+a$ is non-measurable, and there are $\mathbb c$ of them.

Comment: (2) is wrong. First of all, how do you know $a\not=b\implies T+a\not= T+b$? Second, even if we could conclude that, this would only give us $\mathbb{R}$-many non-measurable sets ($T+a$ for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ - this is $\mathbb{R}$-many), not $2^\mathbb{R}$-many.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Translating a set by different amounts gives you different sets; not necessarily disjoint, but, as sets, they are different. The set $T+a$ is different from the set $T+b$; they have different elements, and they are both non-measurable so it is you who is wrong on that count. And I have to complete the proof yet; I was gone for a while and will complete it soon. Still, thanks for downvoting before asking for my clarification.

Comment: No, it doesn't. $\mathbb{Z}+1$ and $\mathbb{Z}+2$ are the same set. (Not just "not disjoint," but actually *the same*.)

Comment: $T$ is a non-measurable subset $\mathbb Z$ is measurable (e.g., it is countable). Can you think of a non-measurable subset $T$ for which $T+a=T+b$, as sets?

Comment: Sure - pick your favorite non-measurable subset $X$ of $[0, 1]$ (say, a Vitali set contained in $[0, 1]$), and consider $Y=\{x+z: x\in X, z\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$ The set $Y$ will again be non-measurable, but for any integers $a, b$, we will have $Y+a=Y+b$ as sets. My example using $\mathbb{Z}$ was just meant to be easy to visualize.

Comment: By the way, this is the **small** objection. The real objection is that there's no way you can use counting translations to conclude that there are at least $2^\mathbb{R}$-many non-measurable sets, since translations will only give you $\mathbb{R}$-many sets. That is, the set of translates of a set $T\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality at most that of $\mathbb{R}$. This is not easily fixable.

Comment: @Noah Schweber: Well, you're right, then take a non-measurable subset $T$ not generated using cyclic properties of $[0,1]/~ == S^1$.  I don't know if I can prove their existence at this point, but I would bet good money they exist. And I said I would delete in a few days if I cannot fix it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: And besides, I am not working in the universe of $[0,1]$, I am working on the Real line, so  $T+1 \neq T+2$ as subsets of the Real line, the two are equal only within $[0,1]Mod1$.

Comment: No, they **are** the same as subsets of the real line. $y\in Y+1\iff \exists x\in X, z\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $y=x+z+1$, but then $y=x+(z-1)+2$, so $y\in Y+2$; similarly, if $y\in Y+2$, then $y\in Y+1$. This means $Y+1=Y+2$, really.

Comment: The length of this comment exchange raised an autoflag summoning a moderator to the scene. I deleted some. If you need to reread them flag or @-ping me.