# What is the cardinality of a non-measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know that $|P( \Bbb{R} )|=|L (\Bbb{R} )|$ ( $L (\Bbb{R} )$ is the set of all Lebesgue-measurable sets).

Note that $L (\Bbb{R} ) \subsetneq P( \Bbb{R} )$.

What is the cardinality of non-measurable set? Is this set countable?

Comment: Are you asking for the size of the set of nonmeasurable sets? Or for the possible sizes of nonmeasurable sets? The former is $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)| $. The latter are not completely determined in $\mathsf {ZFC} $.

Comment: Note that $L(\Bbb R)\neq P(\Bbb R)$ is not provable unless you assume some form of choice.

Comment: Surely a countable (or finite) set is measurable, because singletons are and countable unions of measurable sets are measurable. So a non-measurable set must be uncountable.

Comment: Indeed, it's possible that $L(\Bbb R) = P(\Bbb R)$ if you don't assume the axiom of choice (in some axiomatics, all sets are Lebesgue measurable).  And about the original question : do you assume continuum hypothesis or not?

Comment: Good reference: Measure and Cardinality/James M. Briggs and Thomas Shaffter.

Comment: @Eran. Very thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A standard argument to show that $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb R)$ has the same size as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)$ is to note that the Cantor subset of $[0,1]$ has the same size as $\mathbb R$ and measure 0, so any of its subsets also has measure 0. You can use the same idea to find the size of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)\setminus\mathcal L(\mathbb R)$: Fix a nonmeasurable subset $N$ of $[2,3]$, and note that $N\cup A$ is nonmeasurable for any $A$ subset of the Cantor set. (This was asked before, by the way, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1367129/462).)

The question of what sizes can nonmeasurable sets have is harder. Of course, any such set is uncountable. If $\kappa$ is the least possible size of a nonmeasurable set, then there are nonmeasurable sets of size $\tau$ for any $\tau$ with $\kappa\le\tau\le|\mathbb R|$, by the same argument as in the previous paragraph, so the problem is to see what one can say about $\kappa$ itself. It turns out that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is not strong enough to give us much information: it is consistent that $\kappa=\aleph_1$ while $|\mathbb R|$ itself can be arbitrarily large. It is also consistent that $\kappa=|\mathbb R|$ and $\mathbb R$ can be as large as wanted. Other behaviors are also consistent.

This number $\kappa$ has been studied in the context of cardinal characteristics (or "cardinal invariants") of the continuum, where it is denoted $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal L)$. There are several survey articles containing more information. See for instance the chapters by Andreas Blass and by Tomek Bartoszynski in the Handbook of set theory.

Comment: Another interesting, but easier, question is the possible sizes of measurable sets. Any size is possible, again by the same argument with subsets of the Cantor set, so it is better to ask for the size of measurable sets which do not have measure zero. Any such set must have the same size as $\mathbb R$, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/26373/6085).